# Elements not hiding properly on lightbox open

Tags: html, css, lightbox

would really appreciate some help please!

I used some lightbox code I found online (like I do for every bit of code I need, the noob I am), but when you open something in the lightbox you can still scroll the page and see some of the content behind. I made the z-index like 9999 or whatever, but that's obviously not the issue.

Would anyone mind having a look and letting me know how to fix? Thanks in advance!

Site: https://runplymouthharbour.co.uk/test#step12 (click image to open in lightbox and you can see content below it showing on top)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to include a code sample in your questions as it makes it easier to answer.

But to answer the question, your `z-index` fix won't work as your class `row__container` has `z-index: 1` rule, which overrides the `z-index` you set in the `span` that displays your image (it does this because the `row__container` div is a parent of the `span`).

To fix, remove that `z-index: 1` from `row__container`.